# My SQL inner Join With a table by two condition depending on value of another column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables user_profile and chat_friendlist returns

[chat_friendslist and user_profile table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PULiO.png)

```
SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.friend_id, 
IF(a.user_id=146, e.user_id, d.user_id) as conversation_user_id,   
IF(a.user_id=146, e.first_name, d.first_name) as conversation_first_name,   
IF(a.user_id=146, e.last_name, d.last_name) as conversation_last_name  
FROM chat_friendlist a   
inner join user_profile as d on a.user_id = d.user_id  
inner join user_profile as e on a.friend_id = e.user_id  
where (a.user_id = 146 or a.friend_id=146) and a.status='accepted'
```

[The Results of above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qInqa.png)

I am getting this result

But now I want to add another condition search by first and last name.

Result should be filter by first name and last name.

I have tried with the following query

```
SELECT a.id, a.user_id, a.friend_id,  
IF(a.user_id=146, e.user_id, d.user_id) as conversation_user_id,   
IF(a.user_id=146, e.first_name, d.first_name) as conversation_first_name,   
IF(a.user_id=146, e.last_name, d.last_name) as conversation_last_name  
FROM chat_friendlist a   
inner join user_profile as d on a.user_id = d.user_id  
inner join user_profile as e on a.friend_id = e.user_id  
where (a.user_id = 146 or a.friend_id=146) and a.status='accepted'   
and d.first_name like '%g%' and e.first_name like '%g%'
```

But it returns nothing.

Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Once try with this

```
(d.first_name like '%g%' or e.first_name like '%g%')
```

Comment: I have included the tables... you can try it also.. help me

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
SELECT a.*,  
IF(a.user_id=146, e.user_id, d.user_id) as conversation_user_id,   
IF(a.user_id=146, e.first_name, d.first_name) as conversation_first_name,   
IF(a.user_id=146, e.last_name, d.last_name) as conversation_last_name  
FROM chat_friendlist a   
inner join user_profile as d on a.user_id = d.user_id  
inner join user_profile as e on a.friend_id = e.user_id  
where (a.user_id = 146 or a.friend_id=146) and a.status='accepted'   
and (d.first_name like '%G%' and e.first_name like '%G%')
```

This might be work

Comment: I have tried this one.. Not working.. I have included the tables. you can help me

Comment: @Sibbir Ahmed Check my updated answer and notify me if it is worked or not

Comment: No, still this is not working. I have included the tables you can also run it... or Do you need any information let me.